# How to pass a variable value from model to view using ValidationError (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, validationerror, error-messaging

I am developing an app in Django.

In this app there is a file form.

In the view function associated to base.html I have implemented a message system that publishes a message if the user has not copleted the form correctly and tries to submit it.

```
messages.error(request, ('ERROR: Compile the form properly!'))
```

In my **models.py** I have a clean function that prevents form validation by raising a validation error and printing a message in the console:

```
def clean(self):
    if not (self.file):
        raise ValidationError("No file selected.")

    if not self.Glossary_file.lower().endswith('.xls', '.xlsx', '.xlsm' '.csv', '.xml', '.xlt'):
        raise ValidationError("The selected file is not a spreadsheet.")
```

However, these two messages gets overwritten by the string in views.py.

Let's imagine I re-write my clean method like this:

```
def clean(self):
    if not (self.file):
        error_message="No file selected."
        raise ValidationError("who cares, it gets overwritten by view message")


    if not self.Glossary_file.lower().endswith('.xls', '.xlsx', '.xlsm' '.csv', '.xml', '.xlt'):
        error_message="The selected file is not a spreadsheet."
        raise ValidationError("who cares, it gets overwritten by view message")
```

I would need something like this in my **views.py**, replacing the other line:

```
messages.error(request, (error_message))
```

but I don't know how to pass `error_message` from models.py to views.py.

The ValidationError prevents me to add a `return` in my clean function, which I could use to return `error_message`.

Here is my view function corresponding to form page:

```
def add_file(request):

    if request.method=='POST':

        form = file_form(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            insert_attempt_output="correct"

            messages.success(request, ("ok"))


            return redirect('add_file_template')

        else:
            insert_attempt_output="error"
            messages.error(request, ('ERROR: Compile the form properly!'))

            return render(request, 'add_file_template.html', {'insert_attempt_output':insert_attempt_output})

    else:
        return render(request, 'add_file_template.html', {})
```

Comment: how about validating form? then after calling form.is_valid() you can access validation errors in form.errors

Comment: I am already using it. I added my views.py script in the question. Maybe I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: `form.errors` is the list of errors, including the validation errors coming from your **model**'s clean method. So use that instead of a fixed text in `messages.error()`